# How to append Ajax.ActionLink using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm busy with a ASP.NET MVC 3 site. There should be a view with a list of links. The list is to be populated (or constructed, rather) using jQuery.

Now, previously it worked by just saying in some javascript function (in a seperate javascript file):

`$(ul#Items).append(<li><a href=...>...</a></li>);`

for each item in an array.

But a change to the system now makes it necessary to utilize the functionality provided by Ajax.ActionLink. But if I try to append <%: Ajax.ActionLink ... %> like above, it actually appends it as text and not html (i.e. on the page it displays a list of <%: Ajax.ActionLink... <%>

Any suggestions why this is happening and how to make it work?

Thanks
D

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the following working:

```
$('ul#Items').append('<li><%= Ajax.ActionLink("Hello", "foo", new AjaxOptions {  }) %></li>');
```

Of course if you are using the Razor view engine:

```
$('ul#Items').append('<li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Hello", "foo", new AjaxOptions {  })</li>');
```

And don't forget that in ASP.NET MVC 3 by default jQuery is used by all `Ajax.*` helpers so you might need to include `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` for the link to work.

This being said personally I wouldn't use `Ajax.*` helpers. Here's how I would do it:

```
$('ul#Items').append(
    $('<li/>', {
        html: $('<a/>', {
            href: '@Url.Action("someAction", "someController")',
            text: 'hello world',
            click: function () {
                $.get(this.href, function (result) {
                    alert('ajax success');
                });
                return false;
            }
        })
    })
);
```

---

UPDATE:

I didn't notice that you stated in a separate javascript file. That explains it. You cannot use server side tags in a static file.

Comment: Nope :( Only the li part is recognized. The <%... part; in IE is not recognized and a list of whitespace is displayed; and in Chrome it displays the text <%= Ajax.ActionLink(... for each item in the list.

Comment: The question states "in a separate javascript file", so I guess that's why <%= doesn't work

Comment: Is there a way to make it work even though it is in a seperate js file? Putting js in a seperate file instead of in the view is a mandatory convention used by the team in their projects.

Comment: @Dieter, you can do it in a separate javascript file, you just might need to construct the url in the main view, probably store it either as a global javascript variable or as a HTML5 data-* attribute of some DOM element.